# Shortcut for export PDF on LyX?

Tags: pdf, lyx

Is there a shortcut in LyX for export to PDF?

Is there any way to auto export on save?

Comment: In Lyx you should be able to customize the shortcuts (Preferences->Editing->Shortcuts).

Comment: Ctrl+R views the output in PDF. To me that's already exported...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following works for me on Ubuntu with LyX 2.0.5:

To create a shortcut, go to Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts and click on "new". For the function put in `buffer-export pdf2` (or if pdf2 is not the format you want then look under Preferences > File Handling > File Formats)

To save and export at the same time, either create a new shortcut or edit the current save shortcut, which is found in the same place. Under "show keybindings containing" text box put `buffer-write`. It will show the current shortcut (Ctrl + S by default). Click on it and click "modify". Change `buffer-write` to `command-sequence buffer-export pdf2; buffer-write`.

If you want to get rid of the dialog asking if you want to overwrite (which comes from the export), go to Preferences > Output and change the setting for "Overwrite on export".

Comment: It seems to me this does not work if file is already saved, since `buffer-write` aborts. `command-sequence buffer-export pdf2; buffer-write` seems to work.

Comment: @user21952-is-a-great-name good point! I changed the order. Thanks.