# Short cut for exporting pdf on lyx

Tags: lyx

What is the keyboard short cut for exporting pdf (xetex) on lyx? If there is no existing short cut, how can I create the one ?

Answer (score 1):

The default shortcut for generating a PDF is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, and to update the PDF <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. To make these use XeTeX, go to Document --> Settings --> Output, and set *PDF (XeTeX)* as Default Output Format.

Comment: That is for preview and not export.

Comment: @user34083 Oops, you're right, sorry. Anyway, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89561/shortcut-for-export-pdf-on-lyx, I suppose your question is duplicate of that?

Comment: @user34083 See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71110/can-lyx-automatically-save-the-pdf-output-in-the-same-folder