# Restoring Ctrl+R preview shortcut in LyX

Tags: lyx, preview

I just installed LyX on a new device and noticed that, while I can manually export to a saved PDF, Ctrl+R didn't have the usual convenient effect of creating a preview PDF. I read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89562) answer to a question about exports, and in adding the `buffer-export pdf2` command I accidentally made Ctrl+R export instead of previewing. Can I analogously add a command to instead achieve preview? I tried `buffer-preview pdf2` and `preview pdf2`, but neither worked.

Comment: Does `buffer-view` do what you want?

Comment: @scottkosty Yes, thanks; make it and answer, and I'll upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LFUN to preview is `buffer-view`.

You can see the default bindings [here](https://git.lyx.org/?p=lyx.git;a=blob_plain;f=lib/bind/cua.bind;hb=92bfa07a6205e6e2aae486510c148582e11d6017). You might want to check your user directory to see if you or LyX unintentionally changed the default binding.